# Preview.app: easily print current page only?

Tags: printing, preview

When printing a PDF from preview, is there an easy way to only print the currently displayed page? Now, I look up the page number and enter it two times in the page range. But maybe there is a keyboard shortcut to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preview under Snow Leopard (10.6) has a "Print Selected Page.." under its File menu (or option-command-P).  This works regardless of showing the Sidebar or not.

Comment: Nice, I didn't have 10.6 to test :). Note that my way for 10.7 doesn't require the sidebar to be visible.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (especially the keyboard shortcut). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the version of Preview included in Lion, this is easy. Go to File-> Print...
Click the Show Details button to reveal extra options.
Under Pages, choose Selected Page in Sidebar.

That will print only the current page (and the live print preview will update to show you).
Note that the side bar *does not* have to be visible for this to work.

Comment: Ah, seems like they (finally) included the option in Lion. Nice